# IDataReader to execute stored procedures

Tags: c#, using, idatareader

I am using IDataReader to get the data from db using stored procedure. ie something like this

```
using (IDataReader Reader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(ConnectionString, "StoredProc1", sqlParam))
{
     while (Reader.Read())
     {
     }
}
```

In that case is it required to close the reader manually? my doubt is since we are using the **Using** directive, after execution whether it will close the reader automatically?.

Thanks,

Mahesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `using`, and the returned reader implements `IDisposable`, `Dispose()` will be called automatically. Assuming `Dispose()` is correctly implemented (and it is), it will do whatever is necessary to make sure the object can be safely disposed of. If that requires calling `Close()` it will call Close; Or an internal equivalent we don't need to know about.

Comment: So it will close() and Dispose() reader automatically. ie so we didn't have to bother about it. am i right?

Comment: @mahesh, it will call `Dispose()`, it will not call `Close()`. But Dispose will do *everything* that's needed to properly release all resources used, so one way or another it will do what `Close()` does. I don't want to say `Dispose()` is going to call `Close()` (those there's a good chance it actually does) because that's an implementation detail.